# Error removing Item from state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, graphql, state

I am trying to remove an item from state in React and having trouble. Upon clicking the remove button, the API call is successful (from browser inspector and reloading the page) but the item is never removed from state, therefore still showing the item until the user reloads the page (which is just calling the API to list the items again). Here is my App.js:

```
class App extends Component{
  state = {
    modalOpen: false,
    externalNameInput: "",
    requestorNameInput: "",
    approvalNameInput: "",
    dateLastApprovedInput: "",
    Externals: []
  }

  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

  handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })

  async componentDidMount() {
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listExternals))
    this.setState({ Externals: result.data.listExternals.items });
  }


  handleDeleteService = async externalId => {
    const { Externals } = this.state
    const input = { id: externalId}
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteExternal, { input }))
    const deletedExternalId = result.data.deleteExternal.id;
    const updatedServices = Externals.filter(external => external.Id !== deletedExternalId)
    this.setState({ Externals: updatedServices })
  }

  handleAddService = async event => {
    const { external, Externals } = this.state;
    event.preventDefault()
    const input = {
      externalName: this.state.externalNameInput,
      requestorName: this.state.requestorNameInput,
      approvalName: this.state.approvalNameInput,
      dateLastApproved: this.state.dateLastApprovedInput
    }
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createExternal, { input: input}))
    const newService = result.data.createExternal
    const updatedServices = [newService, ...Externals]
    this.setState({ Externals: updatedServices, externalNameInput: "", requestorNameInput: "", approvalNameInput: "", dateLastApprovedInput: "", modalOpen: false})
  }
  render() {
    const { Externals, externalNameInput, requestorNameInput, approvalNameInput, dateLastApprovedInput} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
      {/*List of Services Formatting*/}
      <Container style={style.last}>
        <div>
          {Externals.map(item => (
            <Table color={colors}>
              <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Service</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Requestor</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Approver</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Last Approved</Table.HeaderCell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Header>

              <Table.Body>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.Cell>
                  <div key={item.id}>
                  <button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteService(item.id)}>
                    <span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  </div>
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{item.externalName}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{item.requestorName}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{item.approvalName}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{item.dateLastApproved}</Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Body>
            </Table>
            ))}
        </div>
        </Container>
        {/*End List of Services Formatting*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true });
```

I believe it has something do from within the handleDeleteService function (obviously):

```
  handleDeleteService = async externalId => {
    const { Externals } = this.state
    const input = { id: externalId}
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteExternal, { input }))
    const deletedExternalId = result.data.deleteExternal.id;
    const updatedServices = Externals.filter(external => external.Id !== deletedExternalId)
    this.setState({ Externals: updatedServices })
  }
```

After reviewing the code multiple times, I cannot pin down what is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line 
`Externals.filter(external => external.Id !== deletedExternalId)` is filtering on the `Id` property (notice the capital I in Id) when I'm *guessing* you want `id`.  So the filter function returns `undefined !== deletedExternalId`, which is true for all items, and thus does not update the state.

Comment: Happy to help :)